# How to read file names from a directory specified on stdin with Go

Tags: go

I would like to read all files from a given directory, and I tried this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("directory: ")
    inBuf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    inDir, _ := inBuf.ReadString('\n')
    strings.Replace(inDir, "\\", "/", -1)
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(inDir)
    fmt.Println(files)
}
```

This will always return "[]" with or without the "strings.Replace" line. Could anyone point out the problem with the code, or provide a easier way to accomplish this task? Thanks!

Comment: first of all, don't ignore errors so you can tell if something goes wrong

Comment: I would like to help, but I'm not sure I understand the full context and why `strings.Replace()` is necessary.  Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because you must strip the \n from the inDir variable, otherwise it tries to list the contents of "dirprovided\n". Something like this might work:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Print("directory: ")
    inBuf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    inDir, _ := inBuf.ReadString('\n')
    inDir = strings.Replace(inDir, "\n", "", -1)
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(inDir)
    fmt.Println(files)
}
```

Edit: also as mentioned above, printing the errors instead of dropping will help. That's all I did to figure this one out.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The way to replace "\n" to "" somehow doesn't work, but the following way works: inDir = inDir[0:len(inDir)-2]   So it's definitely the problem with \n. Thanks again!

Comment: it mean it was `\r\n`

Comment: I don't understand why you must use strings.Replace

Comment: Answer only provides memory location. Update @YOU edit and then try this at end: `for _, v := range files { fmt.Println(v) // or v.Name() }`

Answer (score 0):

Suggested steps:

1. Request directory from user using **bufio** library
2. Determine absolute path based on common path abbreviations using **os** library
3. Read directory contents using **ioutil** library
4. Print absolute path; iterate through directory contents and print name of each item

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // STEP ONE
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Choose a directory: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    dir := scanner.Text()


    // STEP TWO
    if dir[:1] == "~" {
        dir = os.Getenv("HOME") + dir[1:]
    } else if dir[:1] != "/" {
        pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        dir = pwd + "/" + dir
    }

    // STEP THREE
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)

    // STEP FOUR
    fmt.Println("Directory: ", dir, "\n")       
    for _, f := range files {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, ignoring errors is not best practice.  Example here ignores errors for sake of brevity.

Comment: I am a big believer in feedback.  When someone down-votes an answer without providing a comment, then the person who originally posted the answer has no ability to reexamine their code or their interpretation of the original question.   Friends don't let friends down-vote without comments.